# differntiation of functions

Tags: derivatives

Let $f,g$ and $h$ be 3 differential functions.

Given that $f(0)=1,g(0)=2 ,h(0)=3$ and $(fg)' (0)=6,(gh)' (0)=4$ and$(fh)' (0)=5$ then find the value of $(fgh)' (0)$.

I am not able to understand how to solve it. Please help me.

Comment: Have you learned the product rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(fg)'(0)=f'(0)g(0)+f(0)g'(0)$ and so on, you have three equations in $f'(0),g'(0),h'(0)$.  So you can find those.
Then write $(fgh)'(0)$ in terms of $f(0),f'(0),g(0),g'(0),h(0),h'(0)$